Read parameter and value from a config file
I have this code that is supposed to read from file and look up the parameters and read the values. In short I pass at program startup the configuration file and the program should read the values to configure the system. But I don't understand what is wrong and especially why it doesn't read the values.
void read_configuration_file(const char* filename) {
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot open configuration file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char parameter[100];
    int value;
    while (fscanf(file, "%s %d", parameter, &value) == 2) {
        //I inserted debug prints but it doesn't enter this while
        if (strcmp(parameter, "ENERGY_DEMAND") == 0) {
            energy_demand = value;
            printf("energy_demand %d\n", energy_demand);
        } else if (strcmp(parameter, "SIM_DURATION") == 0) {
            sim_duration = value;
            printf("sim_duration %d\n", sim_duration);
        } else if (strcmp(parameter, "ENERGY_EXPLODE_THRESHOLD") == 0) {
            energy_explode_threshold = value;
            printf("energy_explode_threshold %d\n", energy_explode_threshold);
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
}

This is the configuration file from which I read
ENERGY_DEMAND = 1
SIM_DURATION = 1
ENERGY_EXPLODE_THRESHOLD = 1

How could I modify the code to make it work?

Your configuration file has the format %s = %d, so either change your fscanf to include the = or change the configuration file to not use the equal sign.

You're not accounting for the = in your scan; either remove the = from the config items or update your scanf to deal with it: scanf( "%s = %d", parameter, &value)

fscanf(file, "%s %d", parameter, &value)?  That %s format specifier is a buffer overflow waiting to happen.  See Read no more than size of string with scanf()  Note also %s stops when it hits whitespace, so if there's a space in the  parameter string in the file, fscanf() will not read what you expect.

Some other people have already used comments to point out bugs in your code, so I will address a different issue: it is most likely a bad idea to write your own configuration-file parser; instead you should consider using an existing, open-source parser.
Why? Because: (1) using an open-source parser is likely to require less development work and have fewer bugs than writing your own parser; (2) the open-source parser is likely to provide more useful features than your own parser provides.
An internet search for, say, "configuration file parser for c" can help you find some open-source parsers. Alternatively, this Stackoverflow question provides some suggestions.
